# How to include external (DLL) EF Entities so VisualStudio can automatically create a WebAPI controller to them

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dll, asp.net-web-api

i have two projects that share one database. The Entity Data Model of the database is in a separated class library (i'm using Entity Framework 5).

So, one of the projects is an ASP.NET MVC project and i want to include the Entities in my Model, so i could use them in a WebAPI controller.

I have added a reference to the .dll of the database access library and i have included the ConnectioString to the web.config, so the database is fully accessible from my MVC project. But, if try to create a new Controller like this:

***Add -> Controller -> WebAPI 2 Controller with actions, using Entity Framework***

Then, at the "Model Class" section, Visual Studio does not shows my Entities to include them as Model objects, is it possible to make Visual Studio search for my entities at the .dll to automatically generate the controller?

And one more question: How does Visual Studio decide which classes to show as Model Classes and which doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Did you compiled your solution before you tried to add the Models in the new Controller dialog?